# NSString not concatenate

Tags: ios, xml, nsstring, concatenation

I need to generate big XML file. So i create this code

```
int n = 6;

    NSString *carString = @" \n";

    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            if (j!=i){
                NSString *carStr = [@""stringByAppendingFormat:@"<car from=\"%i\" to=\"%i\" /> \n",i,j ];

                NSLog(@"%@",carStr);

                [carString stringByAppendingString:carStr];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",carString);
```

When `NSLog(@"%@",carStr)` give me something like this

```
<car from="6" to="1" />
```

`NSLog(@"%@",carString)` give me empty string

Why? Can you help me?

Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[carString stringByAppendingString:carStr];
```

This create a new string, that you never use or read.
Try:

```
carString = [carString stringByAppendingString:carStr];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 6;

NSMutableString *carString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@" \n"];

for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
        if (j!=i){
            NSString *carStr = [@""stringByAppendingFormat:@"<car from=\"%i\" to=\"%i\" /> \n",i,j ];

            NSLog(@"%@",carStr);

            [carString appendFormat:carStr];
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",carString);
```

Replace `NSString` with `NSMutableString` so that further string could easily be appended .
Hope it will you .